# Raspberry PI freezing

Tags: usb, wireless, power-supply, kernel, java

I am working on a project to getting data from serial device and transmit it to web. I am using kernel 3.2.27 with busybox few start up scripts like sysfs and proc, wvdial daemon to dial USB modem for internet connection and a Java program which fetch data from serial line (/dev/ttyUSB3). I am using `RS485-USB` converter. I am using few modules like `usbserial, ftdi_sio, usb_wwan, option and ppp`. My input voltage is 5.45V and 2A.

All my set up running fine but after 3~4 hours my device freezes. I don't know why this strange problem is happening. Only a few process are running on the PI. Sometimes I am getting a message like `__alloc_pages_nodemask error code 22`.

Can anyone guide me to resolve my issue.

Comment: What size SD card are you using and what class is it. Sometimes the SD card causes that alloc pages error.

Comment: I have got it from element14 along with Raspbian OS, its 4gb.

Comment: OK- So does the official raspbian OS do the same crashing? Remove all addons and scripts. And all i can suggest trial and error. Add a piece and test, add another test some more until you find what crashes. If it crashes with Raspbian and nothing then return the Pi for another.

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee Did you try out what ppumkin said?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness `__alloc_pages_nodemask error code 22` happen for SD card, like file system in SD card is either corrupted or it was unplugged.. But I have just put proper sleep time to my daemon process with a new SD card and problem was resolved ..

Comment: So, it's been fixed? You can create a self-answer and mark it as such, if you like. Otherwise, I can create a place-holder answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

The OP resolved this issue himself, as can be read in [this comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7580/raspberry-pi-freezing?noredirect=1#comment21080_7580) on the original question.

He had to add proper sleep time to the daemon process and put it on a new SD card.

This is simply a placeholder answer until the OP creates a self-answer.